# Converting words table from image to text Vision API

Tags: node.js, ocr, vision

[image: Example table]

So using Google's Vision API I'm trying to convert this table using Nodejs. It would be best if the result would be an array like `[hi: bonjour, bye: au revoir ...]`. Now the problem I'm facing is that I only get the words and their coordinates back from Google when I upload this image. Using some kind of hacky solution I managed to merge the words. For example: I managed to merge 'au' and 'revoir' to 'au revoir', but the solution I have is absolutely not solid.

Does someone have a simple solution to this problem? Im afraid I'm thinking way too difficult, but I cannot find a lot of examples online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My current code: https://pastebin.com/jY5jDrqD (yes it's a mess and not very solid)

Answer (score 2):

By the looks of it you've got nicely formatted input, so it should be pretty easy to get reliable results. Could get trickier if some keys or values are long and take up multiple lines though.

The way to approach this is:

1. Take your collection of entities and split them out into rows
2. For each row sort them by their x position
3. Determine which entities are part of the key and which are part of the value

Splitting them into rows is likely to be the hardest part.

I would suggest approaching it as follows:

1. Take your first entity, calculate the midpoint between its upper and lower y values and its overall height, place it in your first row group
2. Take a second entity and calculate its midpoint, then for each row group check whether the second entity's midpoint lies within it. (I'd suggest making the row group a class that keeps entities in an array within it, and can report an overall upper and lower y value for that row based on the entities it has within it already. You might find averaging entity midpoints and heights works best for this, or perhaps just taking the max and min, or maybe some more sophisticated approach)
3. If your second entity falls outside, then it is placed in a new row group
4. Repeat this with all subsequent entities until they're all placed within different row groups
5. You might consider doing a second pass whereby you check if some row groups warrant merging

Things you might need to watch out for - punctuation marks being recognised as their own entity and falling on the edges of two row groups.

Sorting by x should be trivial, and then determining which entities in a row are key and which are value will come down to a bit of trial and error to find a suitable threshold on the gap between the end of one entity and the start of the next.